# How can i raise float to instance of another class?

Tags: python

I tried to implement [automatic differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation) in python (3.7.4) using augmented algebra of [dual numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_number) , an extension of real numbers with real and dual part (analogous to complex numbers). I now need to extend float operators (like + - * / ^) to them. Addition, substraction, multiplication and division were easy to implement (I did it in same way as [here](http://eviatarbach.com/2013/05/13/dual-numbers-and-automatic-differentiation/)), however, i ran into problems while working with exponentiation.

I have DualNumber class implemented like this :

```
class DualNumber:
    def __init__(self, real, dual):
        self.real = real
        self.dual = dual

    # definitions of __add__, __sub__, __mul__ etc. ...

    def __pow__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, DualNumber):
            return DualNumber(self.real ** other.real,
                              self.dual * other.real * self.real ** (other.real - 1) + self.real ** other.real * other.dual * log(self.real))
        else:
            return DualNumber(self.real**other,
                              self.dual * other * self.real**(other - 1))

def auto_diff(f, x):
    return f(DualNumber(x, 1.)).dual
```

This only allows for instances of DualNumber to be exponentiated. How can i define output of raising float to instance of DualNumber when there is no __rpow__ analogous to reversed variants of other operators ? So that i can perform operations like

```
a = DualNumber(1,2)
5 ** a
```

**Note** : by "float" i mean any representation of real numbers.

Comment: As best I can find, there is no viable definition of <real> ** <dual>.  The concepts don't map smoothly, i.e. preserving "normal" algebraic properties and dovetailing with those of dual numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an `__rpow__`. It's documentation can be found on the [Python data model page](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__rpow__)

```
class X:
    def __rpow__(self, other):
        return "rpow"

x = X()
print(1**x)  # rpow
```

Comment: I believe that the problem is not the syntactic existence; rather, it's the algebraic implementation of exponentiation when the exponent is a dual number.

Comment: The `operator` documentation only shows what is provided by the `operator` module. As it doesn't provide any of the arithmetic `r*` operations, it's not really relevant here.